# sbt publish to a remote server using the credentials

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala project which I build with `sbt`. I want to publish the project into a remote server using `sftp`. I didn't want to enter to every `publish` my username and my password so I decided to use a file `.credentials` located into `~/.ivy2/.credentials`. The problem is that the `.credentials` file is ignored because at every `publish` action, I need to give my username and my password.

## build.sbt

```
name := "myproject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.12",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.6.0"
)

coverageEnabled := true

publishMavenStyle := true

val keyFile: File = new File(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
publishTo := Some(Resolver.sftp("Maven Repository","example.com","/data/www/example.com/html"))

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")

isSnapshot := true
```

## ~/.ivy2/.credentials

```
realm=Maven Repository
host=example.com
user=user
password=foobar
```

What do I need to make in order to fix this issue ?

Comment: I don't see where keyFile or credentials are used, but [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html) specifies this way  `resolvers += Resolver.ssh("my-ssh-repo", "example.org") as("user", "password")`. I believe the same should work for sftp as well

Comment: Your solution works but I didn't want to put the password into the `build.sbt`. Also, this credentials will be used by several scala projects. This is why I want to store into a file like described here : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html. And then, juste add the credentials like in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ivy credentials are only used for HTTP(s) resolvers (see Ivy docs: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/credentials.html).

For ssh/sftp you could be able to use ssh keys, but unfortunately, if you use a ssh-agent to protect your private key, sbt will ask you for your password. The problem is solved in Ivy 2.4, but sbt still uses Ivy 2.3 ( https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1920 )